# When Scrolling down I want to hide images from ListView

Tags: flutter

```
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 100,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Column(
            children: [
            Image.asset("assets/images/a.jpg")
            Text("Item number $index"),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
```

I need the Text to be seen on scroll, but how I can hide the images onScroll?

Comment: you can listen to scroll controller

Comment: Can you please elaborate with any graphical example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ScrollController _ctrler;
  
  late bool _isVisible ;
  @override
  initState(){
    super.initState();
    _isVisible = true;
    _ctrler= new ScrollController();
    _ctrler.addListener((){
      if(_ctrler.position.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.reverse){
        if(_isVisible == true) {
            setState((){
              _isVisible = false;
            });
        }
      } else {
        if(_ctrler.position.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.forward){
          if(_isVisible == false) {
               setState((){
                 _isVisible = true;
               });
           }
        }
    }});
  }
```

then in your ListView

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 100,
  controller: _ctrler,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Column(
      children: [
      Visibility(
        visible:_isVisible ,
        Image.asset("assets/images/a.jpg")
       )
      Text("Item number $index"),
      ],
    );
  },
),
```

Comment: thank you, but I am using  `ScrollablePositionedList`  instead of `ListView` , it contains `ItemScrollController` instead of `controller`

Comment: your snippet code use `ListView.builder` before , thats why i give answer  with listview

Comment: yes by mistake, I'm so sorry